# cucumberJs step-definition having pipe symbol returns undefined value for an input parameter

Tags: cucumberjs

If my step-definition looks like below :

```
When(/^ I validate current date|time having input (.*)$/, function(time)){
console.log('time value is :' + time)
}
```

In my actual `scenario`, i would be calling the above `step-definition` as shown below :

`When I validate current date having input "bla bla"`

**Problem** : When my scenario executes the actual step-definition, it should print `time is : bla bla` (since `console.log` exists in the `step-definition`. But it is giving me `undefined`.

If i change the scenario to look like below(i.e, without `|` symbol), it would print the value that I am sending from my scenario.
i.e,

```
When(/^ I validate current date having input (.*)$/, function(time)){
console.log('time value is :' + time)
}
```

This time it prints the value. I am interested to know why is it breaking when `step-definition` has `|` symbol having input parameter.Any help would be appreciated.

**Note** : I can resolve the issue by writing 2 `step-definitions`(i.e, one having date & the other one having time). But in-terms of coding practise, it's kind of duplicate(redundancy) that does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, cucumber matches its step definitions using regex. In your case, the regex in your step definition is not accurate and so it is not able to match it correctly. Below changes should work.

Feature:
When I validate current "date" having input "bla bla"

Step definition:

```
When(/^I validate current (date|time) having input (.*)$/, function(time)){
console.log('time value is :' + time)
}
```

Comment: I was reading this article([https://blog.czeczotka.com/2014/08/17/writing-cucumber-jvm-step-definitions/]) & found that we need to use `?:` this. 
i.e, in my case **(?:date|time)** it should work. 
This works like a charm.  Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work without `?:`. But once i put that in the step-definition like this `(?:date|time)`, it worked. 

Note : Non-capturing group reg-ex(`?:`) pattern should be present in order to make it work to accept the input parameter that was supplied from the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue with `|` symbol. For some reason(s), we need to use non-capturing group(i.e, `?:`). If we don't use this, it tries to map to a method parameter. Hence in my case, it was returning `undefined` for an input parameter.

There is a `?:` operator (question mark and colon) and if it is present at the beginning of the group it will not be mapped to method parameters.

It worked like a charm.

```
When(/^ I validate current (?:date|time) having input (.*)$/, function(time)){
console.log('time value is :' + time)
}
```

Issue resolved now.